# how to stop uitextview jumping into last line after insert text programmatically

Tags: ios5, scroll, uitextview, line

i really need some suggestion, i need to stop an uitextview jumping into last line after inserting some text programmatically, i have read some identical question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1809289/uitextview-autoscroll-to-last-line), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864069/stop-uitextview-from-jumping-when-programatically-setting-text), [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1939919?start=0&tstart=0),and [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/76921-editing-middle-uitextview.html). i've try all answers in every question, but my uitextview still always jumping into last line after inserting the text, i can make the cursor back into the last position, but i cant stop it jump, and it's make me dizzy when i use my app in simulator or device. Can somebody give me another clue?

this is the code i made for this case, i implement this in `textviewDidChange` delegate method :

```
NSString *textAdd = @"adding text";
NSRange *range = self.codeTextView.selectedRange;

[textview setScrollEnabled:NO];
textview.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

textview.text = [textview.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textAdd]];

textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(range+[textadd length], 0);
```

Comment: did you get any solution?