# UITextView always appears scrolled to bottom of content?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uitextview

I am using storyboard with auto layout, scene contains UITextView with some text in it, you can see in following image:

[image]

But whenever i move to this scene in running application, it would be like following:

[image]
I have researched it a lot and tried following code, even then it not worked for me:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView Starts at Bottom or middle of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622437/uitextview-starts-at-bottom-or-middle-of-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following, may it help:

```
[yourTextView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:YES];
```

OR

set the content offset in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for it to take effect.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
[yourTextView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

OR

in `viewDidLoad`

```
[yourTextView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
```

Comment: i am not sure, but it may have something to do with autolayot.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 4

```
contentTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: 0, length: 0))
```

Comment: If you want to avoid your textview scrolling its content up it's better to use the scrollRectToVisible method.

`self.textView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: false)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked: just setting the UITextView's text property, then calling `scrollRangeToVisible` with an NSRange with location:0, length:0. My text view was not editable, and I tested both selectable and non-selectable (neither setting affected the result).

Code:

```
[textview scrollRectToVisible:NSRange(0, 0) animated:YES];
```