# Is it possible to write a Xamarin Forms Control Renderer that contains a Subclassed Native Control?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, custom-controls, renderer

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to control the **scroll position** of a custom iOS Xamarin `Editor` (`UITextView`) enclosed in a custom `ScrollView` (`UIScrollView`).

The soft keyboard will throw multiple scroll method calls at these controls which result in a huge amount of unpredictable behaviour.

I've read some good [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/864069/stop-uitextview-from-jumping-when-programmatically-setting-text) about how to decouple the soft keyboard and editor controls but the context is for native iPhone development.

Some of the solutions involve subclassing `UITextView` and `UIScrollView`.

My problem is, while I can subclass `UIScrollView`, because `ScrollViewRenderer` directly descends from `UIScrollView`, I can't do so for `UITextView`, because `EditorRenderer` only **contains** a `UITextView` control.

**My question is**: is it possible to write an `Editor` renderer where I can use my own subclassed version of `UITextView`? The subclass would allow me to override a lot of the behaviour that is causing me so many problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I've found my answer.

`EditorRenderer` has this method which I can override to return `MyOwnUITextView` which I have derived from a `UITextView`:

```
public partial class MyOwnUITextView : UITextView
{
    public int TestInt = 5;
    public MyOwnUITextView() : base()
    {

    }
}

class MyOwnEditorRenderer : EditorRenderer
{
    ...
    ...
    protected override UITextView CreateNativeControl()
    {
        return new MyOwnUITextView();

  
        //return base.CreateNativeControl();
    }
}
```

This correctly is coming through in my `OnElementChanged` method.